# Eclipse Android project with javascript code hinting

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, webview

I wasn't able to find a solution and I don't know if it is
   possible at all.

- I have an Android project and with a UI running in a WebView.
- I have some javaScript files that I was hoping to edit in Eclipse but
  I see that code hinting for javaScript doesn't work because it's a Android project.
- JS code hinting works well in a javaScript project in Eclipse

Is it possible to somehow bind JS code hinting to an Android project ?

I have "www" folder (with .js files in it) inside the "assets" folder of the Android project.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that it works with following steps:

1. close the current open js file;
2. switch to javascript perspective;
3. Reopen the js file

It does not work if you open a JavaScript file in Java perspective. It would be nice if it automatically switched to the JavaScript perspective when it is opened in the Java perspective, or switch to javascript perspective when a .js file is opened. :)

Comment: Nope this doesn't work for me. I've tried all kinds of combinations. I guess something else is wrong with my Eclipse environment. I'm using Version: 4.2.1 Build id: M20120914-1800

Answer (score 0):

Just manually switch to the `Web` perspective, provided you have a plugin installed that could do that(  try [Aptana](http://update1.aptana.org/studio/3.2/024747/index.html)). That should work.

Comment: I have the plugin installed but that doesn't do the trick. The html and css code hinting work but the javascript code hinting doesn't. It only works in a javascript project as I said.

Comment: Yes, and the problem isn't code hinting itself but there is no option for javaScript code hinting in a Android project. I guess it does not recognise .js files in where there are suposed to be just .java files in the project. In an Android project Properites I see just propreties for the .java code hinting, and in a JS project I see just the properties for JS code hinting. I'm not able to import any external libraries for that matter. I guess Eclipse does not expect to have JS code in an Android project by default, so i guess it is not at all possible.

Comment: That seems possible. You could file it as a bug, i think. Or a "feature -request"

Comment: Ok thanks, I will as soon as I figure out how to file bugs :)